# Recursive Call throwing with role name 'FOO' from relationship 'Common.*.fk_**_Role' has already been loaded"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

The following error is thrown on the first recursion on line 8 `settings.Roles = new HashSet<string>(settings.Roles.Union(roles.ToList().Select(x => x.Name)));`
 Not sure whats going on here. Anyone have thoughts?

> The RelatedEnd with role name 'FOO' from relationship 'Common.*.fk_*_Role' has already been loaded. This can occur when using a NoTracking merge option. Try using a different merge option when querying for the related object

recursive Function

```
private int AddSecurityRole(IEnumerable<Role> roles, IRoleRepository roleRep, bool recursive = false)
    //private int AddSecurityRole(Role role, IRoleRepository roleRep)
    {
        if (settings == null) return 0;
        if (!recursive)
            settings.Roles = new HashSet<string>(roles.Select(x => x.Name));
        else
            settings.Roles = new HashSet<string>(settings.Roles.Union(roles.ToList().Select(x => x.Name)));
        var res = 0;
        var permissions = roles.SelectMany(x=> x.RolePermissions)?.Select(x => x.Permission);//get roles based on permissions do a linked list, kvp 
        if (permissions != null)
        {
            if(!recursive)
                settings.Permissions = new HashSet<string>(permissions.Select(p => p.Name));
            else
                settings.Permissions = new HashSet<string>(settings.Permissions.Union(permissions.Select(x=> x.Name)));

            /*  foreach (var permission in permissions)
                    if (settings?.Permissions.Add(permission.Name) == true)
                        res++;
                        */
        }
        res = settings.Permissions.Count();
        var parentIDs = roles.Where(p => p.ParentRoleId != null ).Select(x => x.ParentRoleId);
        if (parentIDs != null)
        {
            //get list of parent roles
            //var parentRoles = roleRep?.FindBy(r => r.Id == role.ParentRoleId,

            var parentRoles = roleRep?.GetAll(r =>parentIDs.Contains(r.Id ),
                                             y => y.RoleGroups.Select(x => x.Role.RolePermissions),
                                             z => z.RoleGroups.Select(x => x.Role.RolePermissions.Select(u => u.Permission))
                                            ).Distinct<Role>();

            //pass list in here, with identifier of concat, not new hashset.
            if (parentRoles != null)
                res += AddSecurityRole(parentRoles, roleRep, true);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: How many times are you calling the recursive method.  You are probably in a loop.

Comment: @jdweng that was one problem the other problem is the rolegroups selects were pre loaded in another function, so loading again violated an FK somehow, I have adapted my origional code to clear out the errors. I will post my solution tomorrow.

Comment: Where does `settings` come from? I'd recommend to *only* use `settings.Roles.Add`.